# Adding art to cfmail causing javascript warning and no art display in client email

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I am sending out a receipt to clients on purchase using this CF script.

```
 <cfmail to="#gtOrd.contact_email#" from="no-reply@myCompany.net"
     subject="mtCompany Order #gtOrd.order_lead#-#gtOrd.order_number#"                       type="HTML">
        <cfset order_id = #order_id#>
        <cfset mgd = #mgd#>
        <cfinclude template="order_receipt.cfm">
        <cfmailparam
            file="#ExpandPath('/art/myCompany.jpg')#"
            contentid="showNets"
            disposition="inline" />
</cfmail>
```

The email recipient gets this warning:
"Potentially dangerous scripts were removed from this message. Allow scripts"

The artwork does not show in  the email body. Even if I "Allow Scripts"

The artwork is included as an attachment.

Comment: whats order_receipt.cfm putting in the mail? i'm guessing thats where the problem is coming from

Comment: you're missing an attribute in your `cfmail` tag. You need to add `type="html"` to send an HTML email

Comment: as an aside, there's no need to set `order_id` or `mgd` to the same variable they already are.